# Preserving contractions with textblob ngrams

Tags: python, nlp, textblob

Is there a way to tell #textblob *not* to split contractions like `let's` into `let` & `'s` when creating ngrams? I know they are technically two separate words, but I'd like to maintain them as one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've got two options here:

- Change the [tokenizer used in TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced_usage.html#advanced).
- Post-process the tokens.

The latter is easier, but slower.

**Changing the Pattern**

TextBlob accepts nltk tokenizers, and I'm more familiar with those, so we're going to use that. nltk's WordPunctTokenizer is a RepexpTokenizer with the pattern `"\\w+|[^\\w\\s]+"`:

```
>>> nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer("\\w+|[^\\w\\s]+").tokenize("Let's check this out.")
['Let', "'", 's', 'check', 'this', 'out', '.']
```

Before the disjunction is `\w+`, which indicates word characters. After the disjunction is `[^\w\s]`, which matches anything that's not a character or whitespace--that is, punctuation.

If you want to include `'` in words, to get `"let's"`, then you can just add that character to the word character portion of the disjunction:

```
>>> nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer("[\\w']+|[^\\w\\s]+").tokenize("Let's check this out.")
["Let's", 'check', 'this', 'out', '.']
```

**Post-Processing**

The regex approach isn't perfect, though. I suspect TextBlob's built-in tokenizer might be a bit better than what we could hack together with a regex. If you strictly want to take contractions as one token, I recommend just post-processing TextBlob's output.

```
>>> tokens = ["Let", "'s", "check", "this", "out", "."]
>>> def postproc(toks):
...     toks_out = []
...     while len(toks) > 1:
...             bigram = toks[:2]
...             if bigram[1][0] == "'":
...                     toks_out.append("".join(bigram))
...                     toks = toks[2:]
...             else:
...                     toks_out.append(bigram[0])
...                     toks = toks[1:]
...     toks_out.extend(toks)
...     return toks_out
... 
>>> postproc(tokens)
["Let's", 'check', 'this', 'out', '.']
```

So that gets fixed exactly what you want fixed, but the whole post-processing does add run time to your code.

Comment: just implemented this - using nltk tokenizers & ngrams. worked perfectly - and i can now drop textblob from my project!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work where the `'` is not the first character, for example `doesn't` will be tokenised to `["does", "n't"], but `postproc()` doesn't handle this case.

Comment: Really, the best approach here is to abandon textblob and use a proper tokenizer, but I was trying to stay in the framework of the question.